# A variation of finding 2 disjoint sets with the same sum from a set

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I know it is possible to show the following by using the pigeon hole principle.
Given a set $A_{100} = \{ 1, 2, 3, ..., 100\}$, if a subset $S$ of $A$ is randomly chosen with $|S|  = 10$, there exist two disjoint subsets of $S$ having the same sum.

But when I think about what is the maximum $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that whenever a random subset $S$ of $A_{k} = \{ 1, 2, 3, ..., k\}$, with $|S|  = 10$ is chosen, there exist two disjoint subsets of $S$ having the same sum.

I think this is the same as finding the least $k'$ that all subsets of $S \subset A_k$, with $|S| = 10$, have a different sum. ($k' = k+1$)

I notice that the possible sum of elements in $S$ is at least $\min (S)$ and at most $\sum_{s_i \in S} s_i$. Thererfore the range of possible sum is at most $\sum_{s_i \in S} s_i - \min(S)$.

In the case of $A_{k'}$, $\sum_{s_i \in S} s_i - \min(S) \leq (k'-8) + (k'-7) + \cdots + k' = 9k' - 36$.
Then for $2^{10} = 1024$ of possible subset of $S$, and by pigeon hole principle, $9k' - 36 \geq 1024$ for **no** same sum being found. So $k'$ is at least 118.

But I don't know an efficient way to show whether such $S \subset A_{118}$ exists and so don't know how to process.

I think such $k'$ should exist as for $k'=512$, we can choose $S = \{1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512\}$ and all sums are different integers ranging from $0$ to $1023$.

Comment: If you want a set such that every subset of size $10$ has a different sum, then since $1+2+...8+9+12=1+2+...+8+10+11$, the largest set you can get is $k=11$. Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: In this case, I think $k$ is at least $12$, as we can choose a subset $S$ of ${1,2,3,\dots, 12}$ that has two subsets $P$ and $Q$ of $S$ with the same sum.